# cannot solve syntax error: operand expected (error token is "+")

Tags: bash, math

getting this error, where my code is:

```
#!/bin/bash

# argument passed to script (or any other source if needed like intern to script)
file=$1
rs=$2
clin_sig=$3
mut_type=$4
pos=$6
allele=$7
chain_pos=$8
abs_pos=$(($pos+$chain_pos))
echo $abs_pos
```

where command line is:

```
./program.sh 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
./program.sh: line 11: 1+: syntax error: operand expected (error token is "+")
```

similar questions have been solved using $(()) to do arithmetic, this is not working for me.

Comment: This is because `$chain_pos` is empty. If you do `var=$(( 2 + ))` is what you'll get.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use default value if variable is empty

e.g:

```
pos=${6:-0}
chain_pos=${8:-0}
```

Answer (score 0):

inside `$((…))` you omit the $ in front of variable names:

```
abs_pos=$(( pos + chain_pos ))
```

Comment: You can, but I actually recommend against it. Without the `$`, undefined variables default to 0, where in the OP's case he is at least getting an error.